# /?lastactivity doesn't redirect to latest activity

Tags: bug, status-completed, last-activity

Reproduced on at least SFF and MSE, on:

- Windows 10, Firefox 74.0, logged in
- Android 5.1.1, Chrome 80.0.3987.132, logged in
- Windows 10, Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0, logged out (by copy-pasting a link with the `?lastactivity` parameter)

Clicking on the `/?lastactivity` links does not redirect to the latest activity, only to the question; for instance, if I click the following, I'm redirected to the question itself, not Robert Longson's answer.

> [image: link to an answer as last activity]

---

I do have some userscripts running on Firefox, but none on Edge or Chrome for Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A subtle change here in query string handling behavior in .NET Core and how our shim adapter handled it (checking if there was a *value* for that key - which there isn't in this case).

A fix has been pushed for the next build. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Works perfectly again, thanks for the quick fix!